# I'm trying to run this graph with turtle and turtle is not even coming up

Tags: python, graph, turtle-graphics

## Draw a graph with Turtle

```
import turtle

import random
```

## This is where the code begins

```
def graph(numX, xWidth, scaleY, radius=2):
    minY = 0
    offsetX = -200
    for xVal in range(numX):

        x = offsetX + (xVal*xWidth)
        rand = random.random()
        y = minY + int(rand*scaleY)
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(x,y)
        turtle.pendown()
        turle.circle(radius)

    graph(20, 20, 100, 5)

    turtle.mainloop()
```

## Should it end like this?

Comment: can you check/fix your indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have an indentation problem, you are calling the `graph` function within itself.  Try the following:

```
def graph(numX, xWidth, scaleY, radius=2):
    minY = 0
    offsetX = -200
    for xVal in range(numX):

        x = offsetX + (xVal*xWidth)
        rand = random.random()
        y = minY + int(rand*scaleY)
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(x,y)
        turtle.pendown()
        turle.circle(radius)

graph(20, 20, 100, 5)

turtle.mainloop()
```